# How to define Task with parameters and return value in c++\cli?

Tags: multithreading, delegates, c++-cli, task

i have a class in a cs file:

```
public class ThreadData
{
    private int index;

    public ThreadData(int index)
    {
        this.index = index;
    }

    public static ThreadDataOutput DoWork(ThreadDataInput input)
    {
        return new ThreadDataOutput();
    }
}
```

now, i have c++ code that tries to init a new task and to us the above function:

```
    int numOfThread = 2;
    array<Task^>^ taskArr = gcnew array<Task^>(numOfThread);
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfThread; i++)
    {
        ThreadData^ td = gcnew ThreadData(i);
        ThreadDataInput^ input = gcnew ThreadDataInput(i);
        Task<ThreadDataOutput^>^ task = gcnew Task<ThreadDataOutput^>(td->DoWork, input);
        taskArr[i] = task;
        taskArr[i]->Start();
    }

    Task::WaitAll(taskArr, 300 * 1000);
```

the following code return 2 errors at compile time:

1. can't take address of 'ThreadData::DoWork' unless creating delegate instance
2. cannot convert argument 1 from 'AmadeusWS::ThreadDataOutput ^(__clrcall *)(AmadeusWS::ThreadDataInput ^)' to 'System::Func ^

i also tried to declare a delegate like this in the cs file:

```
    public static Func<ThreadDataInput, ThreadDataOutput> DoWork2 = delegate(ThreadDataInput taskDataInput)
    {
        return new ThreadDataOutput();
    };
```

but i don't know how to call it from the c++\cli code

can anyone assist me to understand how to define cli delegate that can take parametr ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

In order to create a delegate instance in C++/CLI, you need to construct it explicitly, and specify the object that it will be called on separately from the class & method to be called.

```
gcnew Func<TInput, TOutput>(theObject, &TheClass::MethodToInvoke)
```

Note that the method to be called is specified in the C++ style.

Substituting that in to your task creation, I believe this statement will work for you:

```
Task<ThreadDataOutput^>^ task = gcnew Task<ThreadDataOutput^>(
    gcnew Func<ThreadDataInput^, ThreadDataOutput^>(td, &ThreadData::DoWork), 
    input);
```

### Edit

In the code you posted in your comment, you missed the object to invoke the delegate on.

```
gcnew Func<Object^, Object^>(td, &ThreadData::DoWork)
                             ^^
```

Comment: Hi. thx for the answear but this code doesnt compile

what does compile is this:

        task = gcnew Task<Object^>(
     gcnew Func<Object^, Object^>(&ThreadData::DoWork),
     input);

Comment: this code will only compile if DoWork is not static. but in my case it is , so no need to for td object.

Comment: Ah. Because your original code attempting to use `td->DoWork` as the delegate, I assumed that the static was an experimental attempt to get it to compile, not how it was designed. My mistake.